# Why is pam_faildelay.so not taking effect if user clicks cancel button?

Tags: security, centos, pam

There is a problem to validate PAM faildelay rule on CentOS 7 Server with GUI installation. I have added one minute delay between failed login attempts.  The first two lines in system-auth-ac and password-auth-ac files are as below:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=60000000
```

I have performed a test scenario as below:

- User enters wrong password
  Now, signin button and password input field are inactive and login animation will be continuing during one minute ( I saw that login animation has ended after one minute if I have been waiting)
- User clicks the cancel button for example after ten seconds
  Now, user selection screen is shown again (gnome login screen)
- User is selected again and enters wrong password

pam_faildelay.so is not taking effect if user clicks cancel button. What is the problem ? Are there other pam files to edit in order to apply faildelay rule succesfully?

**On 2021-11-04**, thanks to Bogdan Stoica for your comment. I have added the argument nodelay to pam_unix.so as below. Unfortunately same problem is continuing.

First three lines **password-auth-ac** file:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=60000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass nodelay
```

First four lines in **system-auth-ac** file:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=60000000
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass nodelay
```

I think maybe there can be settings between the gnome login cancellation and pam rules. This problem does not exist on CentOS 7 Minimal installation (because of no login cancel button naturally). How can I learn the reason of this problem ?

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/how-does-one-change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password

Comment: I have added the argument nodelay to pam_unix.so as above. Unfortunately same problem is continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add pam_faildelay.so in first line of file - worked for me.